# How can I implement a 1D CNN in front of my LSTM network

Tags: time-series, python, conv-neural-network, lstm, keras

At the moment I reshape my X_train like this:

```py
X_train = input.reshape(1,1,12)
```

```py
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(100,input_shape=(1, 12)))
model.add(Dense(100, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(9, activation='sigmoid'))
```

[image: Model image]

But now I am thinking of implementing a 1D CNN in front of this LSTM layer. Does anybody know how this should be done?

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to reshape the input for 1D-CNN then you can continue to model as follow:

```
cnn_input = Input(shape(?, ?))

x1 = Conv1D(32, 5, padding='same', activation='relu')(cnn_input)
x2 = Conv1D(32, 3, padding='same', activation='relu')(cnn_input)
x3 = Conv1D(32, 2, padding='same', activation='relu')(cnn_input)

concat_layer = keras.layers.concatenate()([x1,x2,x3])
```

After taking the input and apply 1D CNN like this, you can continue to your model as a adding new CNN layers or `Reshape` the `concat_layer` for LSTM and give as an input to it.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I didn't really have to reshape the input, to get the 1D CNN to work, but if I use the ```(1,1,12)``` shape I cant use kernel_size bigger than 1. Please have a look at this issue to better understand what I am talking about https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61204539/dealing-with-batch-size-and-step-size-in-1d-cnn